# Access the only span inside an element using JQuery

Tags: jquery

This might sound like a question already asked before but actually isn't. I know how to access elements using JQuery but in this situation, the parent element has a colon in its name which is making it difficult. The structure is as follows:

```
<fb:comments class='fb_iframe_widget'>
   <span>something</span>
</fb:comments>
```

Note that the span I need to access doesn't have an ID or class and when I use the regular JQuery construct it throws an error due to the colon:

```
var fbspan = $('fb:comments span');
```

If colons are not allowed in tag names, how does Facebook do it in the first place? But more importantly, how do I access that span inside `<fb:comments>`?

Comment: Are you sure that element still exists in the DOM? I believe the FB SDK will change the source you have there in to valid HTML elements. Check the DOM inspector to see what the actual output is.

Comment: _If colons are not allowed in tag names, how does Facebook do it in the first place?_.....that can be achieved with xmlnamespacing.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it by using class if that solves your problem, like

```
$(".fb_iframe_widget").find("span");
```

or

```
$(".fb_iframe_widget span");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the colon. Currently, jQuery is trying to read "comments" as a pseudo element.

```
var fbspan = $('fb\\:comments span');
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sov5d35g/).

Answer (score 1):

use the `children()'` to find span

```
$("fb\\:comments").children("span")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the index of the occurrence of the span you wish to select will not change, you could use **.eq()** to select it.

Ex.

```
$('.fb_iframe_widget').eq(1).css({'color' : 'blue'})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w37t1wzg/